# How to print strings after inputting

Tags: java

User inputs int number. Based on that number user can input the same number of strings. For example:

Input:

```
3
Dave
John
Ben
```

Output:

```
Hello, Dave
Hello, John
Hello, Ben
```

Currently it performs output immediately as only first string is being input:

```
3
Dave
Hello, Dave
John
Hello, John
Ben
Hello, Ben
```

What should I change? Can't get it right by myself

```
public class HelloStrangers {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String stringNumber = scanner.nextLine();
        int number = Integer.parseInt(stringNumber);
        if (number < 0) {
            System.out.println("Seriously? Why so negative?");
        } else if (number == 0) {
            System.out.println("Oh, it looks like there is no one here");
        } else {
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
               String string = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Hello, " + string);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Store the input. Print it later.

```
  String[] list = new String[number];
  for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    String string = scanner.nextLine();
    list[i] = string;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    System.out.println("Hello, " + list[i]);
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to store the strings in an array and then loop through another loop after saving each one:

```
String[] strings = new String[number];
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  String string = scanner.nextLine();
  strings[i] = string;
}
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
  System.out.println("Hello, " + strings[i]);
}
```